# Rail 'Bundle Install' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am new to Rails programming. When i try to run the command 'bundle install' in rails command prompt, the following error comes.

```
C:\Sites\blog>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Retrying dependency api due to
error (2/3): Zlib::BufError buffer error
.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.5.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using bundler 1.7.7
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1
Using execjs 2.4.0
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.8

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/coffe
e-rails-4.0.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing coffee-rails (4.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-rails -v '4.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Even after I install the required gem, the bundle keeps on giving the same message to install a different gem. Could anyone please help me!
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running `gem update --system`

You could also try a temporary workaround by changing the first line in your gemfile from

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source: 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Using either of those two, `bundle` is sure to work.